# Firefox scrollbar not appearing when div height is small

Tags: html, css

I have an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/d3E3M/

I have 3 lines (line 1, line 2 and line 3). You cannot see lines 2 and 3 because the height is too small. I expect to see a scrollbar but do not unless I can the height to 35px

Whenever the height of the div is less than 35px the scrollbar is removed. Is this a firefox bug? Is there anything I can do to get a scrollbar when its suppose to appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is actually working. But 35px is to small for a browser to render a scrollbar.

Comment: So you can see the scrollbar in my code? I don't understand how you can see it but I can't :S

Comment: Yes, i see it. I'm using google Chrome on mac OS. Take a look at that : http://jsfiddle.net/HtTBf/

Comment: It needs to be firefox (I mentioned it in the title). Chrome is fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

you need at least a few pixels to be able to display a scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it properly , but the specified height I guess is too small for a scrollbar to be visible ,I guess a minimum height would be there for a scrollbar to take effect.
Also the line 2 starts to be visible if the height is increased if the height is less than 35px.So I guess there is no available space for the scroll bar to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

scrollbar removed below 35px the reason for scroll bar arrow images having some width and height

if you are added some height to show the scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

That's a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=292284) in Firefox since 15 years ago!!! Please login and follow it. Maybe that helps.