# Firefox doesn't show vertical scroll bar when height is too short

Tags: css, firefox, height, vertical-scrolling

I tried to set a vertical scroll bar on a DIV for short height.
It works for Chrome and IE 10 ( didn't try others).
But Firefox doesn't show vertical scroll bar when height is too short.

Is there a way to let Firefox show the vertical scroll bar even the height is short?

```css
div.title{
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0px; 
 height: 97px; 
 width:100%;
}

body{  
 margin: 0;   
}

div.tableHeader{ 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 98px; 
 height: 28px;  
 overflow-y: scroll;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
    <body>

  <div class="title">
         <h1> Demo how to set vertical scroll bar</h1>         
        </div>        
  <div class="tableHeader">
   <b>test vertical scroll bar, please check right side vertical scroll bar</b>
        </div>


    </body>
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137936/firefox-scrollbar-not-appearing-when-div-height-is-small)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox scrollbar not appearing when div height is small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137936/firefox-scrollbar-not-appearing-when-div-height-is-small)

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar appears also in Firefox, if you want to see the "draggable-bar", try something like...

```
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 6px 0;
```

..to increase the inner content's height.

```css
div.tableHeader{ 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 98px; 
 height: 28px;  
 overflow-y: scroll;
 width:100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
    <body>

  <div class="tableHeader">
    <b>test vertical scroll bar, please check right side vertical scroll bar</b>
  </div>

  </body>
```